# Still problems with profiling EF Database First

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, mvc-mini-profiler

Using EF 4.1 and Mini-profiler 1.7.  Using model-first, scanned from existing database.  EF generates a class that derives from ObjectContext/ObjectSet, not DbContext/DbSet.  I couldn't find anywhere to control that.

I tried the popular solutions, to no avail.

Suffering from frustration, I also tried to directly create my Context with an explicit EntityConnection, which was created directly with the ProfiledDbConnection.  I wanted to bypass any chance that the connection was not the intended type.

```cs
public HomeController() {
try {
    string[] paths = new string[] { @"res://*/" };
    Assembly[] assys = new Assembly[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() };
    MetadataWorkspace mw = new MetadataWorkspace(paths, assys);
    string cnx = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XXXX"].ConnectionString;
    DbConnection cx = MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbConnection.Get(new SqlConnection(cnx), MiniProfiler.Current);
    //DbConnection cx = Database.DefaultConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(cnx);
    EntityConnection ec = new EntityConnection(mw, cx);
    db = new MyContextEntities(ec);
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    Trace.WriteLine("EDM failed: " + ex.Message);
    db = new MyContextEntities();
}
}
```

I have verified that the correct path is taken.  However, when actually running a LINQ query, we get an exception:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbConnection' to type
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'.

The offending statement is:

```cs
return query.ToList();
```

The stack trace is even more interesting, because apparently something inside EF absolutely wants a SqlConnection!

> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.set_DbConnection(DbConnection value)
>   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.set_Connection(DbConnection value)
>   at System.Data.Common.Utils.CommandHelper.SetStoreProviderCommandState(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, EntityTransaction entityTransaction, DbCommand storeProviderCommand)
>   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
>   at System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext
>   context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
>   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
>   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
>   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

Obviously, if I feed it a SqlConnection instead, everything is happy.

What is going on here?  How did this ever work?  Maybe it never worked for EDMX case?  Does the fact that it is ObjectContext-derived have any bearing?

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. Still no workaround :(

Comment: Are you using EF 4.1 'Update 1' by any chance?

Comment: According to NuGet packages, I am using EF 4.1.10330.0 and MiniProfiler 1.7.  I see there are newer versions of both packages, would an update be appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After upgrading EF (4.1.10715.0) and MiniProfiler (1.9.1) packages, and adding MiniProfiler.EF (1.9.1) package, go into the App_Start module (MiniProfiler.cs) and put the following, instead of the `ProfiledDbConnectionFactory` code:

```
MiniProfilerEF.Initialize();
```

And all is well!